# TortoiseGit is Giving Me Exit Code 1

Tags: git, github, version-control, tortoisegit

I am attempting to push my code to GitHub using TortoiseGit, but it is giving me exit code 1.

I have Git Created the repository on the folder, and have successfully committed it, but it just will not push to GitHub.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain the particular steps you took to try to get it to push? The more details the better!

Comment: @chessofnerd I am creating the folder, right clicking and "Git Create Repository Here". Then I am right clicking "Git Commit  -> 'Master'. Then I am clicking 'Push'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the remote url you have set in TorToiseGit for your local git repo.

The recommended approach is to:

- create an empty GitHub repo first
- clone it with TortoiseGit (`TortoiseGit→Clone`, use an https url: `https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>`)
- check your GitHub credentials: `TortoiseGit→Settings→Git→Config`.
- add and commit your code in the local cloned repo
- push